# Can't make the image disappear on small screens with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code that uses Bootstrap and it should make an image disappear on smaller screens.

```
<img src="_images/header.png" class="visible-lg" alt="header image">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly hide rather than display at specific viewport sizes.

If you are using v4, try `hidden-sm-down`

If you are using previous versions, try `hidden-xs hidden-sm`

see the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The class should be: ".visible-lg-*" (add block, inline or inline-block at the end) 
example: .visible-lg-block

```
<img src="_images/header.png" class="visible-lg-block" alt="header image">
```